# Paramiko for SSH cisco UCSM failing

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I am trying to connect Cisco UCSM using ssh through Paramiko. My commands are getting failed. When i enter same commands manually it is working fine. Please Can any one guide me how to fix issue.

Code:

```
import time
import paramiko
import getpass
host = "10.10.10.10"
username = "admin"
password = getpass.getpass("Please enter Password:")
c=paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
c.connect(host,username=username,password=password)
print "connection to %s established" %host
time.sleep(1)
stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command("scope org db")
output = stdout.read()
print output
time.sleep(2)
stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('show service-profile')
output = stdout.read()
print output
```

Output:

```
  Please enter Password:
  connection to 10.10.10.10 established

                                     ^
  % Incomplete Command at '^' marker
```

Manually entered command in UCSM:

```
ucsm1# scope org db
ucsm1 /org # show service-profile

Service Profile:
Service Profile Name Type              Server  Assignment Association
-------------------- ----------------- ------- ---------- -----------
db/SP-DB1
                     Instance          8/7     Assigned   Associated

ucsm1 /org #
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Rather than exec_command, can you try:

```
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
remote_conn.send('scope org db\n')
```